# How to transform items in a PagedList?(Android Arch Component Paging Library)

Tags: android, paging, android-architecture-components, android-paging

Android Architecture Component now introduced [Paging Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging), which is great.

According to the official demo The `DataSource.Factory` now supports `map` and `mapByPage` methods, which means we may transform items in one `DataSource`.

But `DataSource` and `DataSource.Factory` should be in the model layer, not the Presentor/View layer. However, there are plenty of times when we want to transform data in our Adapter(for RecyclerView or ListView), and obviously, this is the Presentor/View layer logic. By now, an Adapter holds an instance of `PagedList`, but `PageList` can't support these operations, which is kinda awkward. Besides, there are still times when we want to add items or remove items to/from a `PagedList`.

So this is a feature request:

1. Support item transformations on a `PagedList`
2. Support item adding/removing to/from a `PagedList`

Any discussion is welcomed.

Comment: I think the Domain model is not the main issue, you can treat just the PagedList as a domain class and abstract the factory and datasoruce in the data layer. The issue I see is when you need to make transformation in the presentation layer.  (assuming arch layers as data-domain-presentation)

Answer (score 3):

I think you need use transformations for `PagedList` instead of `LiveData<List<YourModel>>`.

*For example, I have a list of `Pet`, each `Pet` have `gender`. I need to show paging of `Pet` and filter `gender` in runtime.*

**So, my Dao interface may be:**

```
@Dao
inteface PetDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM Pet WHERE Pet.gender = :gender ORDER BY Pet.id ASC")
    fun getPetsByGenderDataFactory(gender: String?): Datasource.Factory<Int, Pet>
}
```

In `ViewModel` class, I will use `Transformations` to filter `LiveData<PagedList<Pet>>` instead of `LiveData<List<Pet>>`:

```
class PetViewModel {

    private val genderMutableData: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()
    private val petItemsData: LiveData<PagedList<Pet>> = Transformations.switchMap(this@PetViewModel.genderMutableData) { petGender ->
        LivePagedListBuilder(AppDatabase.getDefault().getPetDao().getPetsByGenderDataFactory(petGender), 20).build()
    }

}
```

When user change `gender` of `Pet`, you just update value of `genderMutableData`, it will trigger data source for `petItemsData` and update `Pet` items:

```
fun updatePetItemsWithNewGender(gender: String?) {
    this@PetViewModel.genderMutableData.postValue("female")
}
```

Sorry, I'm using Kotlin for example because you don't flag post in Java language.

Comment: what about add a new Pet? How to trigger PagedListAdapter update with that new Pet?

Comment: @Slim_user71169 this based on your return type of Dao methods. For `LiveData`, `Datasource.Factory<Int, Model>`,... Datasource will trigger changes automatically when models updates.

Comment: I dont think that what you are doing above is a Tranformation. The main point is to pull a PagedList of Model_A from database and transform it to LiveData<List<Model_b>> in ViewModel. Is there any example like that?

Comment: This is not transformation! What OP asking is that, instead of passing `PagedList<Pet>` to `PagedListAdapter` via `submitList`, he needs a method to transform `Pet` to `TransformedPet`, so that he can pass `PagedList<TransformedPet>` to `PagedListAdapter` via `submitList`. Now, the million dollar question is, how do you get `PagedList<TransformedPet>`, because your Dao is returning `DataSource.Factory<Integer, Pet>` ?

Comment: @CheokYanCheng: I explored the source code of paging library before and found that unfortunately there is no way to transform data type unless this functionality gets added to the `PagedList` by owners.

Comment: Do anyone know to transform  PagedList<CustomEntity> to  PagedList<CustomModel>